# How to send nearly 45000 mails through cron job by SMTP Server

Tags: email, cron

I want to send 45000 emails using a cron job via SMTP server.

The problem is when I am sending email using cron, it allows only approx. 400 emails. After that it shows `run execution error`.

Can anyone assist?

Comment: Did you set the php timeout large enough?

Comment: No iea what this has to do with php, actually.

Comment: These emails will be going into the spam folders anyway in >99% of all cases. So what sense does this make? spam filters do bayesian learning these days.

Comment: Yes i changed in php.ini file i.e., max_execution_time = 300000 but problem was same

Comment: No, only near about 400 mails are shooting and coming to inbox not in spam folder

Comment: what if you adapt the code to send the mail in smaller batches? Instead of all at once?

Comment: Yes, I know it but we have to shoot 45000 mail at a time using cron.